# Как получить результат из UnitySendMessage

Tags: c#, unity3d

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как получить результат из этого

```
UnitySendMessage(CALLBACK_OBJECT, CALLBACK_METHOD, [imageSavePath UTF8String]);
```

это код из обжектива но как в юнити получить результат

Comment: Пожалуйста опишите свою проблему по подробнее, выложите часть кода. Откуда вы взяли этот метод?

Comment: Нужно получить адрес выбранной картинки из галерей пример проекта  по [гиперссылке](https://github.com/thedoritos/unimgpicker) 
 а фрагмент 
кода по [гиперссылке](https://github.com/thedoritos/unimgpicker/blob/master/Assets/Plugins/iOS/Unimgpicker/Picker.mm), я ниразу не работал с нативным кодом, я новичок в программирований, а задача такова нужно менять аватарку в игре, выбирая эту аватарку из галерей смартфона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу ответить на ваш вопрос на примере нативного плагина, который я разрабатывал.
При разработке вашего функционала, у вас есть связка C# класс и Objective-C класс. Допустим C# класс называется `MyUnityClass` и вы хотите, чтобы по выполнении какого-то кода, ваш Objective-C код вызывал метод класса `MyUnityClass.CallBackMethod(string parameter)` вам понадобится сделать следующее:

1. В C# классе MyUnityClass определяете метод вида

   `private void CallBackMethod ( string parameter)
   {
    /* ваша логика C# кода здесь */
   }`
2. В классе Objective-C кода
   Объявите (можно константой или передать через параметр) название класса C# кода, к которому будет обращаться C# код:

   `//Name of Unity gameobject to send message`

   `const char *gameObjectName = "MyUnityClass";`

Где-то внутри вашего метода вызов C# кода будет выглядеть так:

```
     const char *message = nil;
     message = [responceString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     UnitySendMessage(gameObjectName, "CallBackMethod", message == nil ? "" : message);
```

При этом, будьте крайне аккуратны с переименованием методов в вашем C# классе, так как они вызываются из нативного кода по строке-названию.

Comment: Большое спасибо! помогло